# Accessing Google Cloud persistent disk from both GKE and independent web server

Tags: gcloud, nfs, google-kubernetes-engine, gce-persistent-disk, google-persistent-disk

Following [this guide](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266), I see how I can create a persistent disk in Google Cloud, than host it with an NFS server.

Now I have an NFS server I can use from my GKE nodes.

However, I want to also be able to post data to it from an independent web server, basically making it the only writer and the nodes the readers.

How can I access the disk remotely without deploying a VM instance of it?

Is it not a recommended use case for GC persistent disks?

Comment: Why can’t you access it over NFS from the web server? NFS has some non-POSIX behaviors if there are multiple clients, but if you only have one writer node, it should basically work as you’d expect out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe it is possible as disks cannot be mounted as read/write on one instance and mounted as read only in another. NFS server would be the way to go.

Comment: So in read only scenario - who is expected to put anything there in the first place?

Comment: Data needs to be there beforehand. Mount as read/write, unmount and mount as read only.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [Cloud **Filestore**](https://cloud.google.com/filestore) as a network attached file storage for Compute Engine instances and GKE instances. That way you could have multiple writers and readers